# Difficulty using std::views::split to populate a std::vector in C++

Tags: c++, split, c++20, std-ranges

I'm facing an issue while attempting to populate a `std::vector` with the results of `std::views::split` in C++. Specifically, I can successfully construct a `std::string` from the items of `std::ranges::split_view` (as shown in the first loop of the code below), but I encounter difficulties when trying to use an iterator to create a `std::vector` directly.

```cpp
// requires /std:c++20 or later
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string rg{ "1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 "};

    // Successful construction of std::string from std::ranges::split_view
    for (const auto& subrange : rg | std::views::split('3'))
    {
        std::string value(subrange.begin(), subrange.end());
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }

    // Issue arises here when attempting to create std::vector
    auto parts = rg | std::views::split('3');
    auto asVector = std::vector<std::string>(parts.begin(), parts.end());

    // The following loop results in a compilation error
    for (const auto& subrange : asVector)
    {
        std::string value(subrange.begin(), subrange.end());
        std::cout << value << '\n';
    }
}
```

Compilation Error:

```
Error   C2665   'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string': no overloaded function could convert all the argument types    
splitView   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33030\include\xutility    241
```

I appreciate any insights or solutions to help me resolve this issue.

Comment: XY problem? appending `| std::views::transform([](auto r) { return std::string(r.data(), r.size());})` as the chosen answer suggest in some case might avoid the vector at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value type of `rg | std::views::split('3')` is `subrange<string::iterator, string::iterator>`, and `string` cannot be constructed through it, that is, `is_constructible<string, subrange<string::iterator, string::iterator>` is false, so the compilation fails.

The ideal way is to use C++23 `ranges::to`:

```
auto asVector = std::ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>>(parts);
```

which is applied *recursively*, so the `string` is first constructed from the `subrange` via (nested) `ranges::to`, which in turn invokes its range constructor `string(from_range_t, R&&)`, and then the `vector` is subsequently constructed.

In C++20 you still need to manually convert the original `subrange` to `std::string`

```
auto parts = rg | std::views::split('3') 
                | std::views::transform([](auto r) {
                    return std::string(r.data(), r.size());
                  });
auto asVector = std::vector(parts.begin(), parts.end());
```